# Combining lists produced from .split() in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This is my code:

```
check = open('test.txt', 'r')
for line in check:
    field = (line.split())
    print (field)
```

It produces this output:

```
>>>['test1', 'Cats', 'Dog']
>>>['test2', 'Zebra', 'Elephant']
```

---

The result I want is:

```
[['test1', 'Cats', 'Dog'], ['test2', 'Zebra', 'Elephant']]
```

Comment: `line.split()` returns a list , you can create before your `for` another list `l` and then inside your `for` just do `l.append(line.split())` or if you want to achieve this with list comprehension   `l=[line.split() for line in check]`

Comment: @dejdej

That's perfect! So obvious too.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should combine the results of a split into a list. There are many ways to do it - for instance, list comprehension:

```
[line.split() for line in check]
```

Or mapping:

```
list(map(str.split, check))
```

Comment: Or a *regular* for loop?

Comment: I'm sorry -- maybe I am doing the mapping way wrong.

k = list(map(line.split, check))
And I got: [['test1 Cats Dog\n']]

Comment: @wwii A _regular_ loop is the slowest and least compact method.

Comment: Both suggested methods produce identical results. List comprehension is faster than mapping, but functionally they do the same thing.